# Watch NetFlix on Chromium or Firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox, google-chrome, chromium

Since Chrome will soon no longer provide updates for 14.04 LTS and this leaves at least a one month gap until 14.04 LTS 64bit comes out I need a way to watch Netflix on either Chromium or Firefox.  I prefer Firefox.  I've tried many of the suggestions in the forums but with out luck.

I've succeeded in converting many of my family members off Windows to 14.04 LTS and I LOVE it, they LOVE it and I spend WAY less time repairing their machines now.  But no Netflix is going to be a problem.

Can someone point me to a reliable way to make this work?

Comment: Chrome will not provide updates for **12.04**, not 14.04...

Comment: And 14.04 LTS 64 bit is already out.  However, I am interested in the answer to your question, because I use an old 32 bit netbook to watch Netflix  and I'd really like to continue doing that using Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the only use that I personally have for Chrome is to make a 'Netflix App' out of it.

```
google-chrome-stable --app=http://netflix.com
```

Running that, or editing the launcher for Chrome to run this command will open Google Chrome and launch the netflix website without any pesky window dressing like a location bar, buttons, tabs.....just Netflix.

Of course going full screen works too, if you aren't multitasking while watching a show or movie.